# How to subtract two datetime in mongo php

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime, query-builder

Here I did the query for subtract but the result am getting null value. Is this correct way for subtract two datetime in project?

**Code:**

```
$arguments = array(      
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            'updatetime_difference' => array('$subtract' =>array('ISODate(2015-05-30T10:01:58.000Z)','$update_date')),
        )
    )
);

$result = $db->aggregate($arguments);
```

Comment: Instead of `array('ISODate(2015-05-30T10:01:58.000Z)'` can you try using MongoDate object: `array(new \MongoDate('2015-05-30T10:01:58.000Z') ... ` ?

Comment: Hi Constantin Guay, Thanks for your update. I worked on above you given MongoDate object, But am getting error " A non well formed numeric value encountered".

Comment: Sorry, with `new \MongoDate(strtotime('2015-05-30 10:01:58.000'))`?

Comment: ok, For static its working fine, But dynamically getting zero value result like for matcihng two db fields values "ISODate(2015-05-30T10:01:58.000Z)" and "ISODate(2016-05-30T10:01:58.000Z)"

Comment: What are you expecting? The result of subtracting two `Date` objects is the number of milliseconds between the two.

Comment: 'updatetime_difference' => array('$subtract' =>array(new \MongoDate(strtotime('2015-05-30 10:01:58.000')),'$update_date')),

I did this, but the result is '0'. 

Static  value : new \MongoDate(strtotime('2015-05-30 10:01:58.000')) and the
Db stored value : ISODate(2016-05-30T10:01:58.000Z)

Comment: How to map this two date.